# OpenGL: "invalid value" error after call to `glGetBufferSubData`

Tags: opengl, glsl

My first question in this community.

I have following code.The code is shortened for clarity, error checks skipped:

```
int creat_ssbo_buf(uint32_t *ssbo, size_t size, size_t unit_size){
  glGenBuffers(1, ssbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, *ssbo);
  glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 
               size * unit_size, 
               NULL, 
               GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
  glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, *ssbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
  return 0;
}

int read_ssbo(uint32_t  ssbo,
              void     *pbuf,
              size_t    size,
              intptr_t  off)
{
 glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
 glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,
                    off, 
                    size, 
                    pbuf);
 glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0 );
 return 0;
}

int compute(...){ /* runs the GLSL code */
 ...
 glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
 return 0;
}

int main(){
 ...
 size_t buf_size = w * h;     
 uint32_t *pbuf = /* some raster image with the size of above */;
 uint32_t  ssbo;

 creat_ssbo_buf(&ssbo, buf_size, sizeof(uint32_t));
 compute(...);
 read_ssbo(ssbo, pbuf, buf_size, 0);
 
 printf(" 0 : %u\n", pbuf[0]);
 printf(" 1 : %u\n", pbuf[1]);
 printf(" 2 : %u\n", pbuf[2]);
 printf(" 3 : %u\n", pbuf[3]);
 printf(" 4 : %u\n", pbuf[4]);

 return 0;
}
```

With the GLSL code as below.

```
layout(std430, binding = 0) writeonly buffer layout0
{
 uint data[];
};

void main(){
 uvec2 pos  = uvec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);

 if(pos == uvec2(0,0)){
  data[0] = pos.x;
  data[1] = pos.y;
  data[2] = 1;
  data[3] = 1;
  data[4] = 1;
 }
};
```

Now that outputs `0,0,1,1,1` as expected. What I want is to read from buffer with some offset. Below is a `C` and `GLSL` code with changes:

```
/* GLSL */
layout(std430, binding = 0) writeonly buffer layout0
{
 uint pad[1]; /* add some padding */
 uint data[];
};

/* C */
...
size_t buf_size = w * h + 1;
...
read_ssbo(ssbo, pbuf, buf_size, sizeof(uint32_t)); /* note the offset */
...
```

And with the offset added, I get an error: `invalid value`. The error fires up after `glGetBufferSubData` call. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S Also, if offset is left as `zero` and the indices of `pbuf` in the `printf`'s are changed to one index greater, the output is correct.

Ask away what code I should add to make things clearer.

Comment: Resolved. As per documentation: `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated if `offset` or `size` is negative, or if `offset+size` is greater than the value of `GL_BUFFER_SIZE` for the buffer object. The `offset + size` is greater than the buffer size.